# Program Not Responding Occurs Randomly in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze

Programs randomly say "Not Responding" for minutes at a time even though we do nothing with the system. Occurs frequently on Chrome. It is better with Firefox but earlier we just witnessed a random freeze while not at the computer.

Windows Explorer, games (on the iGPU), and other programs work fine while the browser is the only thing that freezes. The only extension on the browser is uBlock Origin.

Specs:

- Windows 8.1
- Pentium G2030 @ 3.00 GHz (the task manager usually sits around 1.5-2.5 GHz, not sure if that's a good or bad thing)
- 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Western Digital WD Blue 500GB Internal 7200RPM
- Dell Wireless 1506 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz)

The Dell Diagnostic that comes with the PC reported that there were no issues found. I am unsure why the fans were much louder in the diagnostic than actual computer use. Wouldn't it make sense for the fans to kick in to improve performance?

When the computer freezes, there is usually little to no CPU usage in the task manager (less than 10%). I am not sure if it is a problem with the storage or RAM or something else entirely.

The computer has been dropped before, if that matters. Computer has pretty much only the essentials (Office, etc.) on it and nothing else. Browser works fine after it starts responding again, but I would like to prevent this freezing if possible. The PC does not BSOD.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser: you have a couple of questions included (it is better to have only one question and ask another question with a new page) and the description of the problem changes 'Browser takes a long time to respond' and 'Computer freezes'(these are different problems), a possible reedit will make the question clearer. Is it only the web browsers that are playing up?

Answer (score 0):

This is an often case with many laptops. You could consider doing some of these:

**(1) Removing uBlock Origin:** uBlock Origin is a third-party extension meant to block ads by reading the script of the page and then blocking the particular script. If you don't prefer removing it, you could always disable it.

**(2) Running an Antivirus Scan:** Dell Diagnostics, Dell SupportAssist are programs built to check for any hardware or core software problems and correct them, preventing any serious damage to the laptop computer resulting in a permanent shutdown. You could always download any free Antivirus Software online.

**(3) Booting the Computer in Safe Mode (Without Networking):** Safe Mode without networking seems to disable any networking ports used by backdoor viruses or worms granting the access permission and to Creepers and Hack Tool Servers

**(4) Running a System Cleanup:** Excess of that junk might be responsible for all this. Download any free utility such as CCleaner by Piriform or simply move to the properties panel of the hard disk partition.

**(5) Reinstalling the Browsers:** Reinstalling the browsers would remove any add-ons or extensions causing this problem and might ensure a lag free experience.

**(6) Upgrading RAM:** A laptop with high-end specs like this might lag a little bit with just 4 Gigs of RAM. 6/8 GB would be preferable.

**-->>** Try upgrading to Windows 10. It ensures a lag-free and fast user experience with essentials already built in.

**-->>** Its fine for the CPU to be running at 1.5 - 2.5 GHz as such.

**-->>** Kicking in of Fans and increasing CPU Power will surely increase the performance. Try configuring Advanced Power Options in the Control Panel. And increase in the speed of fans is just because of a test Dell SupportAssist runs!!

Comment: Hello. I changed the power settings from "Dell" to "High Performance" and everything feels much snappier (cpu now at 2.6-2.9 GHz on average). It is a desktop, though. I see that you may have thought it was a laptop since it has been dropped before! Antivirus is installed on this computer and nothing was detected. I'll see how it fares with the new setting. I find it weird how a desktop had power savings enabled. If I buy RAM, should it be the same type or different?

Comment: A same type of RAM would be preferable considering the output and usage...